# Tryouts- Soccer

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The coach of a university soccer team is trying to form a team. From 28 players she wants to pick the best 14 players for her team

1. The coach splits all 28 players into teams of 14 for a scrimmage. Two teams are the same if they have the same players. How many ways can the coach split the players into two teams?

What I've done:

So I used the combination formula to get that 28C14 is 28!/(14!14!). To account for the repetition, would I just have to divide by 2!, or 2?

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: So would the correct answer be 20,058,300 ways?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Notice that if you have the elements $\{1,2,\cdots,28\}$, choosing the subset $\{1,2,\cdots,14\}$ is, in this particular situation, regarded as identical to choosing the subset $\{15,16,\cdots,28\}.$

Comment: Hint: Consider 3 people and you have to make three teams(non-empty!). Clearly there is only one way. Now do the computation to see whether you divide by 3! or 3

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you would.  Choosing $14$ players to be one team also determines who is on the other team.  Therefore, by selecting $14$ of the $28$ players to be on one team, you count each team twice, once when you select those $14$ players to be on the team and once when you choose the other $14$ players to be on the team.  Therefore, the number of ways to select two teams of $14$ players from $28$ players is
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{28}{14}$$

An alternative way to do the problem is to choose the teammates of one player.  Suppose Alexia is one of the players.  To select Alexia's team, we must choose $13$ of the remaining $27$ players to be her teammates.  The other $14$ players must form the other team.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{27}{13} = \frac{1}{2}\binom{28}{14}$$
ways to select two teams of $14$ from $28$ players.